# Checking if binary string input is valid

Tags: c, string, binary, bit-manipulation

I received an assignment to take input from the user (a binary string representing a number) and to print the received number both in decimal and in hexadecimal.

I created an additional function in order to determine whether the input of the binary string is correct (includes only 1's and 0's) or not.

The code is working perfectly fine, except when I input the string in a certain fashion:

Let's say I input **11110000**

The function runs smoothly.

But when I try to input **1111000** as the first string I enter, the function tells me that the string is invalid.

If I input the same string(**1111000**) after I input **11110000**, it works just fine!

Attached is my function:

```
int CheckIfDigits1or0(char *NumString[MAX_SIZE_INPUT+2])
    {
        char digit;
        for (digit = *NumString; digit != '\0'; digit = *NumString++)
        {
            if (digit != '0' && digit != '1' && digit != '\n')
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: In one line: `if (strspn(str, "01") == strlen(str))` but remove any newline first.

Comment: `char *NumString[MAX_SIZE_INPUT+2]` is the problem.  Wrong type.  Post a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You want to scan a string (a pointer to `char`), not an array of pointers to `char`:

```
int CheckIfDigits1or0(char *NumString[MAX_SIZE_INPUT+2])
```

should be

```
int CheckIfDigits1or0(char NumString[MAX_SIZE_INPUT+2])
```

or simply

```
int CheckIfDigits1or0(char NumString[]) // or char *NumString
```

Also, notice that we usually use `return 1;` for `true` and `return 0;` for `false`.